# retrieve historical IoT data bluemix

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, iot

I tried to retrieve historical data of my Internet of Things Foundation devices using CURL command. So I executed this command:

> curl -v -X GET -H "Authorization:Basic api_key:auth_token" -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
>   http://[ogrId].messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/api/v0002/historian/[ogrId]/types/[type]/devices/[mac
>   add]?top=10

But I could not access the data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems with your curl command:

1) It looks like you are setting the basic auth header without encoding it using RFC2045-MIME.  With curl you don't need to set the header yourself, you can simply use the `-u` option, eg:

> curl -u "username:password"  ....

2) You are using `http` instead of `https`.

3) The URL is not quite right - you should not have `orgID` in the path.

The command should probably be more like:

> curl -v -X GET **-u "api_key:auth_token"**
>   http**s**://[orgId].messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/api/v0002/historian/types/[type]/devices/[mac
>   add]?top=10

Comment: I tried this command but I got this message: "Code":"CWLNA0404", "Message":"The HTTP request is for an object which does not exist." }